# Where does Firefox store the sessionStorage content

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage, session-storage

I am trying to find out where Firefox stores the sessionStorage content but have been unable to find so. I am expecting it to be in a SqLite database like the localStorage content is stored but I have not been able to find it.

So far, I have searched all the typical ".sqlite" files in the profile folder such as cookies.sqlite and content-prefs.sqlite etc but they do not seem to have the sessionStorage data.

I also tried to open the special in-memory database that Firefox supposedly creates - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIStorageService#openSpecialDatabase%28%29 but I could not find a way to enumerate the tables present in the database. I could get a connection to the in memory database but i have no clue as to how to figure out the tables etc. that are present in that in-memory database...

Any help is appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

`localStorage` data is saved in the [file `webappsstore.sqlite` in the Firefox profile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#Storage_location_and_clearing_the_data). There is a funny tweak that host names are reverted (`gro.allizom` instead of `mozilla.org`) but other than that it is pretty much what you would expect. There is only one table:

```
CREATE TABLE webappsstore2 (
  scope TEXT,
  key TEXT,
  value TEXT,
  secure INTEGER,
  owner TEXT
)
```

Note that this structure might change in a future Firefox version.

As to `sessionStorage`, it only needs to persist for one browser session. Restarting the browser normally clears it, so it doesn't need to be stored in a database. Firefox still writes it to disk to allow restoring the current browsing session, namely to the `sessionstore.js` file (JSON format). There is a key `storage`, its value is a map from URLs to their corresponding `sessionStorage` data. I am not sure whether this data is complete however given that its main purpose is to recover from crashes.

Comment: That table (webappsstore2 in webappsstore.sqlite) stores the localStorage data. It does not seem to contain the sessionStorage data. Are you certain that it contains sessionStorage data as well bscause I am looking at that table and it only contains localStorage data. I am using Firefox 6.

Comment: @user967973: Sorry, my bad - I misread your question, this database is for `localStorage` data of course. Why do you assume that `sessionStorage` is stored anywhere on disk? It is usable for one browser session only so I am pretty certain that it is only stored in memory. Will change my answer.

Comment: For information, sessionstore.js is now called sessionstore.jsonlz4 and you will need to use a tool like dejsonlz4 (https://github.com/avih/dejsonlz4) if you want to decode the file to read it.

Comment: I also noticed a bug since Firefox 57, sessionStorage is not restored correctly: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=339445#c27