# Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?

Tags: local-storage, web-storage, sessionstorage

Where are sessionStorage and localStorage stored on the client's computer?
Could you tell me the path?

Comment: It's probably browser specific.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha browser+OS specific!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

### Firefox

Firefox stores localstorage in `webappsstore.sqlite` file in the *profile* folder.

#### Firefox (Windows XP):

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows login/user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox (Windows Vista and above):

```
C:\Users\<Windows login/user name>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

or:

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox on linux:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile folder>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

#### Firefox on mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

or:

```
~/Library/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/<profile folder>/webappsstore.sqlite
```

---

### Chrome

Chrome stores in separate files inside the `Local Storage` directory.

#### Chrome on windows:

```
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\
```

#### Chrome on linux:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

#### Chrome on mac:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<Profile>/Local Storage/
```

commonly:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/
```

---

### Internet explorer:

I am a bit unsure, but think this will do the trick

```
%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStorage
```

---

### Opera

As said by OammieR:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\sessions\autosave.win
```

or as said by Kevin Hakanson:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\pstorage\
```

### Sources

- [Where does Firefox store javascript/HTML localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage)
- https://superuser.com/questions/507536/where-does-google-chrome-save-localstorage-from-extensions
- http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory
- My own computer ubuntu 14.10 with Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Can you kindly include a source of all this information?

Comment: @DominatorX i have added sources, but i am unsure about ie

Comment: This is only about `localStorage` right? How about `sessionStorage` mentioned by OP?

Comment: @FranklinYu have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576211/where-does-firefox-store-the-sessionstorage-content#comment92161739_7581138

Comment: In my environments the path of the Local Storage for IE 11
Windows 10: %UserProfile%\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore;
Windows Server 2019: %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\DOMStore
The path is stored in the registry:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\LowCache\Extensible Cache\DOMStore\CachePath

Comment: Please 1 question, if I saved a local storage key and value to track the user for example user X i store key visit , and value his IP for example ,  if new user visit my website when I check the key I will not find the visit key is that true, what I mean can I use this way to detect each new user visit my website check the visit key and if not so he is new user? thanks

Answer (score 1):

LcalStorage and Session storage are stored as per the browser specific paths (like we have for Cookies)....Also it is kind of limited to the Sandboxed environment of the application.
So, only the domain which sets them can read or access it.

Again also remember that only the user has control over expiry of these storage.

Answer (score 1):

I found this (Opera)

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Opera\Opera\sessions\autosave.win
```

and another from

[Where does Firefox store javascript/HTML localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7079075)

Answer (score 1):

The data for Opera (version 12.14 on Windows 7) was located under
`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Opera\Opera\pstorage\`

A `psindex.dat` contained the index to the actual data files.  I visited [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) and the quirksmode [HTML5 Test - storage](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/html5_storage.html) to get data saved.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferences>
  <section id="BA27342AD231CFCE350305FA85EB6ED1D2C57ABC">
    <value id="Type" xml:space="preserve">localstorage</value>
    <value id="Origin" xml:space="preserve">http://todomvc.com</value>
    <value id="DataFile" xml:space="preserve">pstorage\00\07\00000000</value>
  </section>
  <section id="DAA00EFF4F10589343DE5A9AD5C47BD8F28FFFD4">
    <value id="Type" xml:space="preserve">localstorage</value>
    <value id="Origin" xml:space="preserve">http://www.quirksmode.org</value>
    <value id="DataFile" xml:space="preserve">pstorage\00\0F\00000000</value>
  </section>
</preferences>
```

The quirksmode test page let you interactively use the localstorage APIs, so I effectively executed the following code:

```
localStorage.setItem('Name','Value');
```

For Firefox see [Where does firefox store javascript/HTML localStorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage/14901354#14901354) and for Chrome see [How is HTML5 WebStorage data physically stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669184/how-is-html5-webstorage-data-physically-stored/14887525#14887525).

Opera seems to base64 encode the JavaScript unicode strings in the `pstorage\00\0F\00000000` file.

```
<ws>
<e><k>TgBhAG0AZQA=</k>
<v>VgBhAGwAdQBlAA==</v></e>
</ws>
```

Below are the Base64 values above, also encoded as hex and as a string (where `\0` represents `String.fromCharCode(0)`).

```
Base64: TgBhAG0AZQA=
Hex: 4E0061006D006500
String: N\0a\0m\0e

Base64: VgBhAGwAdQBlAA==
Hex: 560061006C0075006500
String: V\0a\0l\0u\0e\0
```