# Where does Chrome save its SQLite database to?

Tags: database, sqlite, google-chrome

Google Chrome stores internal data such as browser history in a SQLite database; where is this saved to?

Comment: Web SQL locations by system for Google Chrome:

Windows Vista or 7 \n \Users\_username_\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
Windows XP

\Documents and Settings\_username_\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
Mac OS X

~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases
Linux

~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases

Comment: I can't delete my answer while it's accepted

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Windows Vista or later:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases
```

Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Application Support\Google\Chrome\Default\databases
```

Windows 10:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History
```

Mac OS X (and macOS—sub-path changes between versions but are all under this main path):

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/*
```

Linux:

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/databases
```

Comment: On Mac OS X (Yosemite) its `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/History`

Comment: @Kyslik, do you happen to know the on for Mac OS (Sierra) ?

Comment: @Jun I bet its same since it depends on Google Chrome implementation; I will update soon (1-2 weeks) to Sierra, will come back and confirm.

Comment: @Kyslik I found it on another thread. Thanks!
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<Profile>/Local Storage/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored

Comment: Well I do not see it there in Mac path mentioned! Is it any different for Mac- 13.* version?

Comment: @Kusum it's still there. The main databases don't have a db extension (nor any extension). For example, the main history one is now at `/Users/[your_username]/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/History`

Answer (score 0):

Mac

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/databases
```

Here are they are organized by URL for every site you have accessed, except for Datbases.db and Datbases.db-hournal