# what is location of my sql database in html5 application

Tags: ios, iphone, html

I am trying to create html5 + sql database in my iOS application. I am using following syntax.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("test", "1.0", "Test DB",  5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

Getting db object here . But just want to know at which physical location this database is creating? is it local storage or somewhere in document directory ?

Comment: [(tut) Introducing Web Databases](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/), [(git)DB locations](https://gist.github.com/shazron/2127546)

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed part of the offline storage space. 
It's separate from Web Storage (aka localStorage), so you won't find your database in the localStorage object.

Offline storage consists of *Web Storage* (aka localStorage), *Web SQL Database* (the one you asked about), *IndexedDB* (another kind of database) and *FileSystem* (for storing large files, experimental).

html5rocks has an [excellent description of web storage and the varieties it comes in](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/?redirect_from_locale=it).

Comment: But what is the location of physical db which is created ? Can I see that in document folder ?

Comment: It's basically a browser technology, so it's up to the browser to store it anywhere it wants. But have a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored).