# Jquery local storage. Where is it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm using the local storage functionality on a website using JQuery and it occurred to me that I have no idea where information is actual being stored. After some research the best I could find was that its stored "Locally". Does anyone have anymore information on this subject?

EDIT:
I appreciate the responses and I do now feel more informed. However im still struggling to find the local storage location specifically in IE11 on windows 10.

Comment: The precise details almost certainly vary from browser to browser and possibly from platform to platform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored)

Comment: Waht you mean by where is it , 
if i understand what you mean ,Local storage is that  the browser stores the information on it's embeded database .

Comment: The local storage is stored in the web browser, if you inspect this page you can see all the local storage variables.

Comment: @JorgeMejia where would the local storage variable be when inspecting

Comment: You can see in the DOM tab

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter where it is.

As a Front End **Developer** you can access it through the browser `LocalStorage` API.

As a **User** you can access it through developer tools.
[image]

The exact implementation varies from browser to browser...

Answer (score 0):

This is browser specific and path may vary depending on the OS. Couple of them are listed below:

For Chrome(windows):
%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\

For Firefox
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\webappsstore.sqlite
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\\webappsstore.sqlite

Comment: Please flag duplicate requests. :)

Answer (score 0):

The local storage variables are stored in the web browser, you can access inspecting the page and then you can see all the DOM objects in the DOM tab.

You can use the filter to find the specific DOM object in this case the local storage.

[image]