# Where does Electron store the indexed db files on a Mac?

Tags: indexeddb

I have not been able to successfully find where Electron stores the data for indexed db files on a Mac. Some posts indicate that it is stored under

> /Users//Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default

But I found no files in this directory that ever got updated when I stored data to an indexed db. Even performing a search on the Mac to find the last modified files does not show anything.

Comment: I found this question indirectly; I would have replied earlier if an `electron` tag had been added too...

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43912928/where-an-electron-applications-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored), HTML5 localStorage is 
stored in the User Data directory accessible by:

```
require('electron').remote.app.getPath('userData')
```

On macOS, this would be:

> ~/Library/Application Support/[app's name]

I guess the same applies for the IndexedDB data, possibly in the sub-directory named "Local Storage"...