# Show Div After Redirect user using ajax in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code that redirects user to another page

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/ajax-send-otp.php",
    data: {
        mynumber: mynumber,
        userCountry: userCountry
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data == 2) {
            $("#otpVerifyDiv").slideDown(500);
            window.location = 'free-listing-new.php';
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Now On Another Page There is A Div-Id With `#otpVerifyDiv` which is hidden. so i wants to show that div. *so is it possible to show div after window location. ?*

I don't need any parameters to be send with url for some reasons.and also do not need ay other js like jquery-cookies.js
i tried

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data == 2) {
        //SHOW DIV 
        $("#otpVerifyDiv").slideDown(500);
        //THAN REDIRECT
        window.location = 'free-listing-new.php';
    } else {
        alert(data);
    }
}
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" id="otpVerifyDiv" align="center" style="display: none;">
 //Some Contetnt Here
</div>
```

So is it possible ?

**My Plan**

is jquery provide any temporary storage or else so where i store data and send data from one page to another like cookies session.

Comment: you would have slide it down in the document ready of the page you are redirecting to

Comment: where is the code of the other page? the redirected one

Comment: @Webster TP :  "free-listing-new.php"  in this file please add this  code  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#otpVerifyDiv").slideDown(500);
});

Comment: So what if request isnt send. still it will be shown. and i dont want that. i just want whenever request would be submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Approach:**

Setting a localstorage variable on success:

```
if (data == 2) {
    localStorage.setItem("otp_verified", 1);
    window.location = 'free-listing-new.php';
}
```

Then on `free-listing-new.php` check:

```
if ( localStorage.getItem("otp_verified") == 1 ) {
    $("#otpVerifyDiv").slideDown(500);
    localStorage.removeItem("otp_verified");
}
```

**Second Approach:**

On success, post a variable to `free-listing-new.php` by creating a hidden form with JS:

```
if (data == 2) {
    $('body').append($('<form/>', {
        id: 'hiddenForm',
        method: 'POST',
        action: 'free-listing-new.php',
        style: "display:none;"
    }));

    $('#hiddenForm').append($('<input/>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        name: 'otp_verified',
        value: 1
    }));        

    $('#hiddenForm').submit();                
}
```

Then on `free-listing-new.php` check posted variable with PHP's super global `$_POST['otp_verified']`

Comment: Its Really Great Answer. is this supports in all browser

Comment: Ensure your browser support localstorage, in fact all of latest browsers do. Second solution will definitely work.

Comment: check [localStorage Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#AutoCompatibilityTable)

Answer (score 0):

Since you using php, you can use condition on the header of the page to prevent people from visiting the page unless they are redirected from a specific page.
on the page they are redirecting to, then you have to use the code as stated by Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

You may do this by checking that user came from which url by `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. if you get the `free-listing-new.php` in `HTTP_REFERER` you can show the your div which you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set local/session storage on succes if the redirect page is in same domain. On coming to the redirected page check that storage data and display the div.

Answer (score 0):

On the success response, you should use `localStorage.setItem("key", "value");` instead of cookie/session. This function will store the value temporarily in your browser storage.

Usage : store value of `otp_verified` on success side and redirect to `free-listing-new.php` page and check for value using `localStorage.getItem("key");` and then remove the item from local storage using `localStorage.removeItem("key");`.

Set item in local storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```

Get item from local storage

```
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Remove Item from local storage

```
localStorage.removeItem("key");
```

Comment: Thankyou Your answer would be useful.Where the value stored if i use localstoreage. is it similler to cokkies ?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored