# Where is sessionStorage data stored?

Tags: javascript, browser

When sessionStorage.setItem("number",2) is executed, where does number gets stored? Is it in the local browser or the server where application is hosted? Please mention the path/file for Chrome browser, if it is local.

Comment: F12 -> Application tab -> Storage -> Session/Local storage.. on chrome. It is a SQLite db native in the browser.

Comment: It is stored on the user's computer.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Are you sure it goes onto the file system? Local Storage does, obviously, since it's persistent, but Session Storage isn't

Comment: It is stored locally, not remotely. Where _exactly_ it's stored is browser-dependent, and doesn't particularly matter to the developer as long as it's understood that it's _local_ and _temporary_.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm not sure what the browser does behind the scenes, but both local and session storage are accessible in that tab I mentioned. I presume session storage has the same structure as local, but it is cleared upon browser/tab closing...

Comment: It is accessible in the browser. The question was where it is stored. Anyways, thanks I got the answer now. @DontVoteMeDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not stored on the server, since we're still in client side when you're talking about `Window.sessionStorage`. It's stored in a file called "sessionstore.jsonlz4". In any case, this question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7581138/12383690).

Answer (score 0):

The values are stored by browser in the user's computer. You can test it in e.g. chrome console. To read value use

```
sessionStorage.getItem("number");
```